# What will happen with existing ec2 machine

Tags: terraform

I have few ec2 machines running created from aws console manually. They are not under terrafrom.
If i want to use terrafrom now to create new VPC and ec2 machine does it will delete my old machines ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Terraform will not delete old machines in aws (created by aws console). That is because whenever you run terraform script to create something, it will create state file which acts as reference copy for terraform. In your case if you create any resources (like ec2 VMs) in AWS, you will end up having both machines (the one created by manually and second set created by terraform)

Read here more about terraform

https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/infrastructure-as-code?in=terraform/aws-get-started